# Custom object with __iter__() not returning what is defined in __tuple__()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, object, methods

**In a custom object with `__iter__()` defined, when calling `tuple(obj)`, it returns the data of `__iter__()` in tuple form, but I want it to return from `__tuple__()`.**

This is a really big class, and I don't want to paste it here. I instead wrote a smaller example of my problem.

```
class Example:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.data = [a, b]

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(reversed(self.data))

    def __tuple__(self):
        return map(str, self.data)


ex = Example(2, 3)

print([x for x in ex])  # Should return the data from __iter__().
>>> [3, 2]  # Reversed, good...

print(tuple(ex))  # Now calling: __tuple__().
>>> (3, 2)  # Should have returned ["2", "3"].
```

If you need to see all of my code, ask, and I'll put it in a Pastebin. I just wanted to save you the effort of sorting through all of those extra methods.

Does `__iter__()` override the `__tuple__()` type? For some reason I can't get it to change to return what it should from `__tuple__()`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where exactly did you get the idea to implement a `__tuple__` method? It's not in the [data model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html). This is the behaviour you should have expected.

Comment: There's no way `print(tuple(ex))` printed `[3, 2]`. That's not a tuple.

Comment: Please vote to close this because it would destroy my rep if it stays. I had assumed that `__tuple__()` existed, and to be honest never thought it wouldn't. After all, `__str__()` exists.

Comment: It *is* closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`__tuple__` isn't a thing. `tuple` doesn't look for a `__tuple__` method to perform conversion-to-tuple. I don't know where you got that idea.

Comment: Because `__str__()` exists.

Comment: @spikespaz, an understandable chain of reasoning. "`__str__` and `__int__` exist, so maybe there are dunder methods for every built-in type", one might think. But this turns out not to be the case.

Comment: @Kevin New vocab term: dunder methods. Never knew. Friend kept referring to them as "magic" declarations.

Comment: @spikespaz: Note that the dunders are just a naming convention; any "magic" of magic methods doesn't have anything to do with the underscores. For example, `next` was the magic method for retrieving an item from an iterator on Python 2.